# Cannot find dymo printer in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, printing

I try to print labels with a Dymo printer from Chrome. I use the javascript sdk.

Only when i find printers with my script i get the following console log error:

Uncaught No DYMO printers are installed. Install DYMO printers. 
I changed the settings like the dymo website said. Does anyone know how to print from chrome?

When i do this with IE or firefox there is no problem.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Sample DYMO Label Plug-In</title>


<script src="http://labelwriter.com/software/dls/sdk/js/DYMO.Label.Framework.latest.js"></script>
    <!-- your script second -->
    <script>




            function OnLoad()
            {
                //GetCurrentPlugin();
                GetDYMOPrinters();

                //GetPaperTray();
                //GetMRUList();
                //GetObjectNames();
                //GetLabelImage();
            }


            function GetDYMOPrinters()
            {
               // alert(" Testing 1");

                var printers = dymo.label.framework.getPrinters();
                if (printers.length == 0)
                throw "No DYMO printers are installed. Install DYMO printers.";
                //alert("dfdsfd");
                var printerName = "";
                for (var i = 0; i < printers.length; ++i)
                {
                    var printer = printers[i];
                    if (printer.printerType == "LabelWriterPrinter")
                    {
                        printerName = printer.name;
                        break;
                    }
                }

            //var label = dymo.label.framework.open("MyText.label");
            label.SetObjectText("Text", "John Smith");

            //alert(" Testing 2");   // Here this alert also not working .
            label.print("DYMO LabelWriter 310");
            }
     </script>

    </head>
    <body onload="OnLoad()"><form action="" method="post" id="DYMOLabel">
        <center>
        <h2>DYMO Label  Example</h2>
         <input type=button value="Get DYMO Printers" onClick="GetDYMOPrinters()">
     </center>
    </form>




    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any errors in the chrome developer tools console?

Comment: No, Only Uncaught No DYMO printers are installed. Install DYMO printers

Comment: you're loading this as a local webpage, i.e. `file:///` not `http://` ?

Comment: Oh wait, this relies on some plugin or something - the plugin is installed and enabled in `chrome://plugins/` ?

Comment: Do i have to install a plugin or delete one. Because there is no plugin that blocks the printer.

Comment: brief look at the code refers to a plugin

Comment: I asked Dymo about this problem. They say this is not possible in chrome because chrome blocked the dymo plugin.

Comment: ouch ... must be a nasty plugin :p

Answer (score 1):

The Framework plugin for Chrome stopped working in 2014 because Chrome dismissed NPAPI, see this [blog post](http://developers.dymo.com/2014/12/04/dymo-label-framework-and-chrome/).

However, there since August 2016 they have created a new solution to this issue [here](http://developers.dymo.com/2016/08/08/dymo-label-web-service-faq/):

> In the past, developers had to provide a browser-specific plug-in for
>   each major web browser.  Nowadays, most browsers have phased out
>   native plug-in support.  Google, for example, stopped supporting
>   Chrome their NPAPI browser extension in September 2015.  In response,
>   we released the DYMO Web Service as a new cross-browser solution
>   allowing third-party developer applications the ability to interface
>   with the DLS SDK in a seamless, browser-agnostic fashion.  It handles
>   all printer-related requests from the JavaScript Library that the DYMO
>   Label Framework browser plug-ins used to perform.

However, it seems that the [JS SDK examples](http://www.dymo.com/en-US/online-support/online-support-sdk) are still not quite working even in 2019. But the examples from this [blog post](http://developers.dymo.com/2016/11/29/sample-samples-samples/) did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me today runs ok with sdk 2.0, (i download .js into my project)

```
<script src="js/DYMO.Label.Framework.2.0.2.js"></script>
```

i read a label definition from an xml file, and print:

```
var label = dymo.label.framework.openLabelXml(datosxml);

var printers = dymo.label.framework.getPrinters();
    if (printers.length == 0)
       throw "No DYMO printers are installed. Install DYMO printers.";

    var printerName = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < printers.length; ++i)
        {
         var printer = printers[i];
         if (printer.printerType == "LabelWriterPrinter")
            {
             printerName = printer.name;
             break;
            }
         }

     label.print(printerName);
```